# Excel Workbook Update

Tags: excel, connection

I need to connect two workbooks so when one workbook changes the other workbook mimics the same changes and vice versa. The workbooks structure is the exact same as they are replicas of each other. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy
Install a *Workbook_Open* macro in each workbook that will open the other workbook.  Then use *Change* event macros in both workbooks to create the synch.